# How do I check if an HTML element is empty using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call a function only if an HTML element is empty, using jQuery.

Something like this:

```
if (isEmpty($('#element'))) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: `$('#elem').text().match(/\S/) || alert('empty');`

Answer (score 631, accepted):

```
if ($('#element').is(':empty')){
  //do something
}
```

for more info see http://api.jquery.com/is/ and http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

**EDIT:**

As some have pointed, the browser interpretation of an empty element can vary. If you would like to ignore invisible elements such as spaces and line breaks and make the implementation more consistent you can create a function (or just use the code inside of it).

```
  function isEmpty( el ){
      return !$.trim(el.html())
  }
  if (isEmpty($('#element'))) {
      // do something
  }
```

You can also make it into a jQuery plugin, but you get the idea.

Comment: Line breaks are considered as content to elements in FF and Chrome.

Comment: @Corneliu is correct. I posted an answer below that takes that into consideration. This was a major source of frustration for me on a recent project

Comment: Doing this with a function is nice of course, but if you want it more "embedded" (and a bit challenging), I would recommend manipulating the prototype of jQuery or using the great "filter" function ability of JQ...

Comment: Is this equivalent to:
`if(row===row.empty())` ?

Comment: @iloo, `.empty` does not do what you think it does. It does not check if an element is empty, it does empty the element.. :)

Comment: "the browser interpretation of an empty element can vary" It doesn't, at all. Every browser considers an element that contains whitespace to *not* be empty for the purposes of the :empty selector, even if you don't consider jQuery's implementation. More likely, the browser interpretation of an empty element is at odds with what *authors* consider to be emptiness.

Comment: @Paolo: No, they're not. Not for the purposes of :empty anyway.

Comment: I found myself trying to use this a few times when the element isn't already wrapped in jQuery, which produces an error on `el.html()`.  To fix that, I've modified it always wrap jQuery around the provided element like so:   `function isEmpty(el){ return !$.trim($(el).html()); }`

Answer (score 125):

I found this to be the only reliable way (since Chrome & FF consider whitespaces and linebreaks as elements):

```
if($.trim($("selector").html())=='')
```

Comment: A slightly more compressed version can take advantage of empty string's falsy-ness:

    `if(!$.trim($("selector").html())`

Comment: I don't think they consider them "elements", but they consider them nodes, which is IMO correct. You could also do `if($("selector").children().length === 0)` or `if($("selector > *").length === 0)`.

Comment: I think you're confusing "elements" with "nodes".

Comment: $("selector").html().trim() === ''

Comment: I do not know why but method from this answer: if($.trim($("selector").html())=='')  worked. .is(':empty') did not!

Comment: The problem with `is(":empty")` is that its interpretation depends on which CSS version spec you're looking at. CSS4 defined that to include elements which have only whitespace, older specs defined it to only include elements without any child nodes (DOM keeps text and whitespace as text nodes).

Answer (score 79):

White space and line breaks are the main issues with using :empty selector. Careful, in CSS the :empty pseudo class behaves the same way. I like this method:

```
if ($someElement.children().length == 0){
     someAction();
}
```

Comment: I choosed that above because I had HTML comments in my DIV.

Comment: By far the most elegant solution, should be the correct answer.

Comment: Note that `$.children()` does not return text or comment nodes, which means this solution only checks is the element is empty of _elements_. If an element that contains only text or comments should _not_ be considered empty for your needs, then you should use one of the other solutions.

Comment: @sierrasdetandil for `select` elements is perfect. the condition can also be `if(! $el.children().length)`.

Answer (score 29):

```
!elt.hasChildNodes()
```

Yes, I know, this is not jQuery, so you could use this:

```
!$(elt)[0].hasChildNodes()
```

Happy now?

Comment: +1 I used your approach inside a jQuery `filter` function as I didn't want to use jQuery inside the function unless necessary.

Comment: If I consider whitespace-only to be empty `<div class="results"> </div>`, this statement will returns false. https://jsfiddle.net/ytliuSVN/0pdwLt46/

Comment: @PennyLiu which is correct because a space is a [text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) in an HTML document.

Answer (score 19):

```
jQuery.fn.doSomething = function() {
   //return something with 'this'
};

$('selector:empty').doSomething();
```

Comment: Great! I like constructions without ifs.

Comment: totally agree with @Nikolay, It isn't useful for my specific situation but I'll remember it for the future!

Comment: well, this wouldn't work when you have to apply 'this'

Comment: What else would `this` be besides the jQuery element @ZealMurapa ?

Answer (score 13):

If by "empty", you mean with no HTML content,

```
if($('#element').html() == "") {
  //call function
}
```

Comment: careful, whitespace and line breaks could cause html to not == '' but element still be empty. Check my answer below for another solution

Answer (score 11):

In resume, there are many options to find out if an element is empty:

1- Using `html`:

```
if (!$.trim($('p#element').html())) {
    // paragraph with id="element" is empty, your code goes here
}
```

2- Using `text`:

```
if (!$.trim($('p#element').text())) {
    // paragraph with id="element" is empty, your code goes here
}
```

3- Using `is(':empty')`:

```
if ($('p#element').is(':empty')) {
    // paragraph with id="element" is empty, your code goes here
}
```

4- Using `length`

```
if (!$('p#element').length){
    // paragraph with id="element" is empty, your code goes here
}
```

In addiction if you are trying to find out if an input element is empty you can use `val`:

```
if (!$.trim($('input#element').val())) {
    // input with id="element" is empty, your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Empty as in contains no text?

```
if (!$('#element').text().length) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address elements whose contents are images (don't ask how I came up with that...)

Comment: @BadRequest No, hence the question mark after "as in contains _no text_?" :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option that should require less "work" for the browser than `html()` or `children()`:

```
function isEmpty( el ){
  return !el.has('*').length;
}
```

Comment: Refers to jQuery’s [has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/) function, not JavaScript’s [Set.has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) or [Map.has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has). Note, though, that the `"*"` selector selects only elements, and does not select e.g. text nodes. Thus, `<p>text</p>` would be considered empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
if($('selector').html().toString().replace(/ /g,'') == "") {
//code here
}
```

*Replace white spaces, just incase ;)

Comment: Wouldn't `!/[\S]/.test($('Selector').html())` work better, once you find some whitespace you know it's not empty

Comment: Why the /i in the regex flags? Are there upper and lower case versions of the space character?

Comment: thanks, updated my answer. I have no idea why I have added /i

Comment: @AlexisWilke Yes there's \s lowercase space character and \S uppercase space character.

Comment: @RobertMallow, Maybe regex supports \S, however, Unicode defines whitespaces as Cc, Zs, Zl, Zp as shown here: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/PropList.txt -- upper case is Lu...

Comment: @RobertMallow, also `The production CharacterClassEscape :: S evaluates by returning the set of all characters not included in the set returned by CharacterClassEscape :: s.` from http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.12

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML == "" || null
```

or

```
$("element").html() == "" || null
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla javascript solution:

```
if(document.querySelector('#element:empty')) {
  //element is empty
}
```

Keep in mind whitespaces will affect empty, but comments do not. For more info check MDN about [empty pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty).

Answer (score -1):

```
if($("#element").html() === "")
{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for `jQuery.isEmptyObject()` ?

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isemptyobject/

Comment: This question is about empty DOM elements, not empty JavaScript objects.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a jQuery filter based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/6813294/698289

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  trimmedEmpty: function(el) {
    return !$.trim($(el).html());
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**JavaScript**

```
var el= document.querySelector('body'); 
console.log(el);
console.log('Empty : '+ isEmptyTag(el));
console.log('Having Children : '+ hasChildren(el));


function isEmptyTag(tag) { 
    return (tag.innerHTML.trim() === '') ? true : false ;
}
function hasChildren(tag) {
    //return (tag.childElementCount !== 0) ? true : false ; // Not For IE
    //return (tag.childNodes.length !== 0) ? true : false ; // Including Comments
    return (tag.children.length !== 0) ? true : false ; // Only Elements
}
```

try using any of this!

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
document.getElementsByClassName('topbar')[0];

document.querySelectorAll('div')[0];
document.querySelector('div'); // gets the first element.
​
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (!$('#el').html()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Line breaks are considered as content to elements in FF.

```
<div>
</div>
<div></div>
```

Ex:

```
$("div:empty").text("Empty").css('background', '#ff0000');
```

In IE both divs are considered empty, in FF an Chrome only the last one is empty.

You can use the solution provided by @qwertymk

```
if(!/[\S]/.test($('#element').html())) { // for one element
    alert('empty');
}
```

or

```
$('.elements').each(function(){  // for many elements
    if(!/[\S]/.test($(this).html())) { 
        // is empty
    }
})
```