# How to replace empty html tags with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code that I want to insert or replace with a desired set of code if it is blank. Any direction in Javascript or jQuery?

If html code equals this:

```
<td id="Display1234"></td>
```

change to:

```
<td id="Display1234">
    <select name="ShippingSpeedChoice" onchange="RecalcShipping(this);" style="">
      <option value="101" selected="">Free</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: At what point in the page's lifecycle does the new content need to be added?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if div element is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535733/how-to-check-if-div-element-is-empty)

Comment: @ScottMarcus After the page has loaded. There is a glitch in our ecommerce store that intermittently does not populate the field. The box has to be selected to be progressed.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to start by getting all the elements on the page (as I'm assuming you don't know which ones are empty).

```
// need to use Array.prototype.slice because getElementsByTagName
// returns an HTMLCollection and not an Array
var allElementsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'));

var emptyElements = allElementsArray.filter(function(element) {
  return !element.innerHTML; // returns true for all empty elements
});
```

I don't know what data to insert but you can then loop through the `emptyElements` array;

```
emptyElements.forEach(function(element) {
  element.innerHTML = 'some content or HTML';
});
```

Comment: missing a peren

Comment: also, i have to downvote because when i tested this it returned all the tags in the head, meta, link, script, and other tags that should not have HTML content. gotta say, it is a cool idea though.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. fixed. Instead of `document` use `document.body`. This will only grab elements inside the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following for a pure JavaScript solution:

```js
var td = document.getElementById('Display1234');

if (td.innerHTML.trim() == ""){
  // Creating the select element
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  select.setAttribute('name', 'ShippingSpeedChoice');
  select.setAttribute('onchange', 'RecalcShipping(this);');
  select.setAttribute('style', '');

  // Creating the option element
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.innerText = "Free";
  option.setAttribute('value', '101');
  option.setAttribute('selected', '');
  
  // Appending elements to td element
  select.appendChild(option);
  td.appendChild(select);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td id="Display1234"></td>
</table>
```

Comment: i'm being a hypocrite becuase i didn't do this in my answer, but `if(td.innerHTML.trim() == ""){..}` would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Display1234').html('your html');
```

Comment: This only changes the content of the element with id `#Display1234`. It doesn't check if that element is empty. And it doesn't check all elements. I know the OP was unclear but I highly doubt this is what they were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
// if the div is empty
if($("#Display1234").html()===""){
    // create a a <select> element
    var $sel = $('<select name="ShippingSpeedChoice" onchange="RecalcShipping(this);" style="">');
    // add an option to the select element
    $sel.append('<option value="101" selected="">Free</option>');
    // add the select element to the div.
    $sel.appendTo("#Display1234");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var theCell = document.getElementById("Display1234");
  if(theCell.textContent.trim() === ""){
  theCell.innerHTML = '<select name="ShippingSpeedChoice" onchange="RecalcShipping(this);" style="">     <option value="101" selected="">Free</option></select>'
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="Display1234"></td>
  <td id="other1">something</td>
  <td id="other2">something else</td>
</tr>
</table>
```