# How do I check to see if a field has a value before executing document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript

This probably isn't very complicated but I'm not a coder by trade so I'm sure I am missing something here.

Here is what I have so far.

```
function buildURL (){
          url = document.getElementById("url").value;
          source = document.getElementById("source").value; //required
          campaignId = '-_-' + document.getElementById("campid").value; //required
          brand  = '-_-' + document.getElementById("brand").value; //required
          brand2  = '-' + document.getElementById("brand2").value; //optional
          brand3  = '-' + document.getElementById("brand3").value; //optional
          medium  = '-_-' + document.getElementById("medium").value; //required
          product = '&cm_mmca1=" + document.getElementById("product").value; //optional

          if (url.includes('?')) {
              url = url + '&cm_mcc=';
          } else {
              url = url + '?cm_mmc=';
          }

          document.getElementById("fullURL").innerHTML = "URL: " + url + source + campaignId + brand + brand2 + brand3 + medium + product ;
       }
```

Now, the url part works great. It prints to screen as soon as I enter a URL in a text box in a form I created and it updates as I make changes. The problem comes with the additional values I print to screen. Everything that proceeds each variable's `document.getElementById` prints to the screen immediately. This is fine for the required variables but not the optional variables. I'm thinking the solution is to prevent all fields from being passed to `document.getElementById("fullURL").innerHTML` unless there is a value in the field but I am not sure how to do that. Suggestions?

Comment: I know it can be hard to come up with the right search terms, but please do try before posting a new question.  I tried "javascript check if element is empty", and found many questions and answers here on SO with code you can copy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if div element is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535733/how-to-check-if-div-element-is-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check each of the option values, and if the value is not an empty String, assign a special value to the variable, else just return an empty String, having no effect on the concatenated final URL:

```js
function buildURL() {

    url = document.getElementById("url").value;
    source = document.getElementById("source").value; //required
    campaignId = '-_-' + document.getElementById("campid").value; //required
    brand = '-_-' + document.getElementById("brand").value; //required
    medium = '-_-' + document.getElementById("medium").value; //required

    // OPTIONAL VALUES: (Use trim() to ensure no white spaces affect our checks)

    const brand2Value = document.getElementById("brand2").value.trim();
    // ( brand2Value ) ? essentially works much like ( brand2Value !== "" ) ?
    brand2 = brand2Value ? '-' + brand2Value : ""; //optional

    const brand3Value = document.getElementById("brand3").value.trim();
    brand3 = brand3Value ? '-' + brand3Value : ""; //optional

    const productValue =  document.getElementById("product").value.trim();
    product = productValue ? '&cm_mmca1=' + productValue : ""; //optional

    if (url.includes('?')) {
        url = url + '&cm_mcc=';
    } else {
        url = url + '?cm_mmc=';
    }

    document.getElementById("fullURL").innerHTML = "URL: " + url + source + campaignId + brand + brand2 + brand3 + medium + product;
}
```

---

**Additional notes:**

- Is there a reason why the function variables (`url`,`source`,`brand`,etc.) are not being declared with `var/let/const`?

Make sure you always declare variables with either let or const,
   otherwise they will become available in the global scope, which is
   something we try to avoid in JavaScript.

Comment: Initially I was looking at the variables being global since I also submit the values in these fields to a Google Sheet but other then that it was/is a newb error. 

Now, this code works pretty good with one flaw. If I set an optional value it will not update unless I make a change to one of the required fields (source, campaignId, brand or medium. It seems like I might need some type of eventListener?

Comment: How is the buildURL function triggered at the moment? @DK_Connection

Comment: You probably need an Event Listener on the change event.

Comment: Actually, it's not being triggered at all with a funciton call. Right now everything is being triggered by inputs into fields and selections in dropdowns.

Comment: I take that back I trigger it with `oninput` and `onchange` which was my problem. I hadn't implemented those on my other fields and dropdowns.

Comment: Maybe this is for another question but how can you take the input, which sometimes contains a space, and encode that space when you capture it?

Comment: You are probably looking for encodeURI or encodeURIComponent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI