# Checking if selectors are blank in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, string

I am currently using a .js file with jQuery commands to find certain elements of a .xml file. I have been able to gather all the data I want easily, however am having a bit of difficulty with the presentation.

I am using the same .js script for the loading of multiple .xml files. The data is gathered in an html document and in list form. Here is the code:

```
        $upgrade1 = $(xml).find("upgrades").eq(0).next();
        $upgrade2 = $(xml).find("upgrades").eq(1).next();
        $upgrade3 = $(xml).find("upgrades").eq(2).next();
        $("#upgrades").append($upgrade1.text() + "<li>" + $upgrade2.text() + "</li><li>" + $upgrade3.text() + "</li>");
```

Now as you can see first the selectors compile the text they need and then it is added to the `<li class ="upgrades">`. Now the issue here is that some .xml files will only have 1 or 2 upgrades rather than all 3. Yet the function will still draw out blank bullet points due to the `<li>` elements in the .append()

The easiest solution is the use an if statement, however I can't seem to find anywhere how you would check if the selector is blank? There are only mentions of checking form elements, but this is not helpful to me. Possibly a way to check for an empty string or a string of less than 1 character? I don't know...

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: maybe look [here:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `length`.

```
if ($('whatever').length == 0) {
  // It's empty
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use your selector implicitly by invoking an each on your query.

```
$("whatever").each(function () {
    var ctl = $(this);
    ctl.text("bob jones");
});
```

In this way you're automatically casting off instances where you don't get any results back.