# How to make a <tr> invisible if it's <td>'s are empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a table which contains 'n' rows dynamically generated. All `<td>`'s may or may not contain data. I want to hide or delete '`<tr>`' if all it's td's are empty.

I don't know how to parse through all `<td>`'s and make sure it's empty or not.

example table as follows,

```
<table id='ex_table'>
  <tr>
     <td>one</td>
     <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the above table last row need to be hidden since all it's `<td>`'s are empty. I prefer jquery to do this.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't actually have to inspect the `td` elements. You can select the rows and use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out those with text content, i.e. only keep those which are empty:

```
$('#ex_table tr').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === '';
}).hide(); // or .remove()
```

This works because `.text` gets the *combined* inner text of all descendants and `$.trim` removes whitespace characters that might occur due to your HTML formatting (but are not actually content).

---

If you have cells which contain HTML elements but no text content (e.g. icons styled through CSS), and you want to keep those, you'd have actually have to test whether a cell contains HTML or not. The approach is basically the same as testing for text content

```
$('#ex_table tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).html()) !== '';
    }).length === 0;
}).hide();
```

only this time we count the number of cells in a row that contain HTML. If there is none, the row is considered empty.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$(function(){
    $('#ex_table tr').each(function(){
        var val = $(this).text().trim();
        if(val == ''){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#ex_table tr').each(function){
  if($(this).text()==''){
    $(this).remove();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight jQuery you say?

EDIT: I'd use Felix's answer.. just change ".hide()" to ".remove()" if you'd like to delete the element.

```
$('tr').each(function(){
  var hasValue = false;
  $(this).children().each(function(){
     if ($(this).html() != "")
        hasValue = true;
  });
if (!hasValue)
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var hide;
$("tbody").find("tr").each(function(){
    hide=true;
    $(this).find("td").each(function(){
        if($(this).html()!='') {
            hide=false;
        }
    });
    if(hide==true) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```