# How to check if any child exist in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `<div>` with several child's inside it which is removed one after another and I want to check when all elements inside are removed .

I tried checking with `if($('#data').html()=="")` but its not working, probably because of white spaces and tab spaces.

Keeping track of each and every elements and checking can be done but I am sure it will be worse idea for this simple task so is there any easy way to do this ?

Comment: Do you have ids or classes on the children?

Comment: did you try with $('#data').html().trim()

Comment: inside it there exist another div and p and they dont have any id/class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if($('#data').children().length > 0)` is the best solution in my opinion 
or shorter `if($('#data').children().length)`

[API](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.find('*')`, the reason why we are passing `*` inside it is, `.find()` cannot be called without parameters as `.children()` do. But the better option would be using `.children()` at this context.

```
if($('#data').find('*').length) {
  //its empty
}
```

or you can use `:empty` selector,

```
if($('#data').is(':empty')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `children()` function to get all child elements 
http://api.jquery.com/children/

and check the array length

```
if($('#data').children().length){
   //do smth
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#data').is(':empty')){
  //do something
}

if($.trim($("selector").html())=='')
```

See more: [How do I check if an HTML element is empty using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Use .children() in jquery to find the children is present or not

```
   if($('#data').children().length > 0) {


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your children are elements of some kind try to use the following:
$('data').children().length == 0

note that white spaces and characters are not considered children

you can check if there is text content using:
$('data').text().length ==0

Note That new line are also characters