# JQuery Node check if not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My *html markup* can look as following:

```
<h2></h2> <!-- empty -->
<h2>text</h2> <!-- not empty -->
<h2><p>text</p><h2> <!-- not empty -->
<h2><p></p>/<h2> <!-- empty -->
<h2><p><span></span></p></h2> <!-- empty -->
```

Is there a way to check if the `h2`-element itself or the `h2`-element with *n-children nodes* contains any **html**-content.

So far I have tried

```
 if ( $('h2').html() !== '' ) ...
 if ( $('h2 *').html() !== '' ) ...
 if ( $('h2').html().length ) ...
```

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I want this code working for every *h2*. The number of children nodes/nested children nodes within the *h2*-node is unknown.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery

Comment: As Moshikaro said, look there and don't forget to check about children `$elem.children().length == 0`

Comment: I have created jsfiddle demo, please check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/turepcw6/1/)

Answer (score 3):

What about `:empty`?

```
if ($('h2').is(':empty')) {...}
```

Comment: :empty is bad in FF, Safari

Answer (score 2):

Just check if the element you want has children and also check if has any text value.

```
$('h2').children().length === 0 && !$('h2').text();
```

Comment: This won't work for text nodes... `<h2>text</h2>`

Comment: @RGraham you are right, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `.text()` instead of `.html()`:

```
 if ( $('h2').text().length )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use:

```
if ($("h2").html().trim().length == 0) {...}
```

This works for text nodes too!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h2").each(function(){
    if ($(this).html().trim().length == 0)
      $("#result").append("Empty<br />");
    else
      if ($(this).text().trim().length == 0)
        $("#result").append("Empty<br />");
      else
        $("#result").append("Not Empty<br />");
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2></h2> <!-- empty -->
<h2>text</h2> <!-- not empty -->
<h2><p>text</p></h2> <!-- not empty -->
<h2><p></p></h2> <!-- empty -->
<h2><p><span></span></p></h2> <!-- empty -->

<div id="result"></div>
```