# Remove P tag with non-breaking space inside of it via JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent, paragraph

So I am receiving unclean content from an API that our content publishers are using and I am getting P tags with non-breaking spaces inside of them and I want to remove the non-breaking space and the P it is in. It would be nice if they cleaned up their content before they published it to the API, but I just need a quick way to remove this via JavaScript or jQuery. I get this error when using the code below. "Syntax error, unrecognized expression:  " Thanks for any help.

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>

$("p").each(function() {
    $(this).find('&nbsp;').remove();
});
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select your paragraph elements, filter out the ones that contain only `&nbsp;` using `.filter()`, then use `.remove()`:

```
$('p').filter(function(){
   return this.innerHTML == '&nbsp;';
}).remove();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u0d7c9dp/3/)

Or:

```
$('p').filter(function(){
   return !$.trim($(this).text());
}).remove();
```

Which, because `.text()` handles HTML decoding for you and `$.trim()` removes outer whitespace, will remove any paragraph that contains only spaces I.E

```
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: Hey I actually have a question, whats does passing the underscore as the first param do?

Comment: The same thing as passing `a`, `b`, `c`, .. as the first param, that was from a previous answer when I misunderstood the question.

Comment: So there is no separate significance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(p).each(function(){
 $(this).html($(this).html().replace("&nbsp;", ""));
 $(this).replaceTagName(''); 
 // or $(this).contents().unwrap(); much faster
});
```

Comment: "I want to remove the non-breaking space **and** the P it is in"

Comment: That solves part of my problem. Is it possible to remove the P tag that non-breaking space was inside of also?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$('p').filter(function () {
    return $(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').length === 0
}).remove()
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/k9rgbzs5/)**

While you said "I want to remove the non-breaking space and the P it is in", you only need to remove the P since that will take the `&nbsp;` with it.

Comment: Sorry for my wording of the question. Thank you.