# is:empty not working for dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div `listOfTodos` that is empty by default. No white space inside the html. I also have a textbox that when enter is pressed it appends text to `listOfTodos`. For some reason `is:empty` doesn't work and it always says it's empty.

My code for checking is:

```
if ($('#listOfTodos').is(':empty')) {
    console.log("empty");
} else {
    console.log("not empty");
}
```

Then above this code I also have:

```
$("#someTextbox").keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $('#listOfTodos').append('<label>Some text</label>'); } 
});
```

The label above is saved and is retrieved on every reload. What's going on?

Comment: Please provide a **complete** example. It's not clear when your `if` statement is executed.

Comment: give jsfiddle , its free

Comment: You can get the HTML inside de DIV and check its length

Comment: Helo , fiddle is working fine. Your html is having some issue .

Comment: Check this out, it might help.  The answer has a way of making sure that empty is what you think it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery

Comment: If your element contains whitespace `is(':empty')` may not work.

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/pywhdyw3/2/

Comment: Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trbj1a6v/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Doesn't JS run code from top to bottom? I have the keypress above the if statement inside my js file.

Yes, but the event handler is not executed until the event is triggered, which is not possible until *after* the whole script executed.

I.e.

```
$("#someTextbox").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#listOfTodos').append('<label>Some text</label>');
    } 
});

if (....) { }
```

will execute the `if` statement only *once* after the event handler *was bound*.

You have to put the `if` statement inside the handler if you want to run it after the *event fired*:

```
$("#someTextbox").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#listOfTodos').append('<label>Some text</label>'); 

        if ($('#listOfTodos').is(':empty')) {
            console.log("empty");
        } else {
            console.log("not empty");
        }
    } 
});
```

Or put it in a function if you want to run that logic in multiple places:

```
function isEmpty() {
    if ($('#listOfTodos').is(':empty')) {
        console.log("empty");
    } else {
        console.log("not empty");
    }
}

// run on load
isEmpty();

$("#someTextbox").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#listOfTodos').append('<label>Some text</label>');
        // run on change
        isEmpty(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Right, but I'd like the `if statement` to run when the page is accessed because I have some information saved and it currently appends to the `listOfTodos` div. So, if there is nothing saved, then `listOfTodos` should be empty and the `if statement` should check that to make sure and send some sort of message...

Comment: @Jamie: Then put that logic inside a function and call the function whenever the content could have changed. That's what functions are there for.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if ($.trim($('#listOfTodos').text()) == '') {
  alert("empty");
} else {
  alert("not empty");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enjak1cp/16/)

Comment: Why should they do that? What's is the problem with `:empty`?

Comment: Curiously I get an error on the first line of `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: @FelixKling , if there are whitespaces, `:empty` will still consider Some data is there , so it considers white spaces . So use of trim is proper

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com: Quoting the OP *"No white space inside the html."*

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com DIdn't work either. Still displayed `empty` even though it wasn't.

Comment: @Jamie: Again, please provide a complete example. It's not clear whether the `if` statement is executed *after* the event handler was executed.

Comment: Doesn't JS run code from top to bottom? I have the `keypress` above the `if statement` inside my js file.

Comment: @Jamie: Yes, but the event handler is not executed until the event is triggered, which is not possible until *after* the whole script executed. It seems you have to learn the basics of event handling.

Comment: I think it is not the answer