# If a div inside of a div is empty change the background color of the parent CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to check if `status_comment_holder` is empty and if it is then I want to change the background of `comment-container` without having to refresh the page, at the moment, I am appending comments to `status_comment_holder` and removing the comment when they remove their comment, I am not too sure if I can do this with css or jquery so I have marked tags for both.

```
<div class="well well-small comment-container" id="comment-container"">
  <div class="status_comment_holder" id="image_comment"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
if($('#image_comment').is(':empty')){
    alert("fhfhf");
    $('.well').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
}
```

With no avail, it's not even alerting for some reason.

Comment: please post your JS code that you have tried as well...

Comment: Your problem here id="comment-container"" you have two ""

Comment: @Ashot Khanamiryan that was just a type when writing down on here.

Comment: `.is(":empty")` returns true only if node is **completely empty** (even without line breaks). Note that an empty `<div>` if no other style is applied (`margin`, `padding`, `height`, `min-height` and so on) has 0 pixel height and is then invisible. Also note that same may be done with CSS (as Aaron answer - now deleted - shown).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this out:
[How do I check if an HTML element is empty using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery)

Your idea seems to be fine enough, maybe the div actually has a whitespace inside? you could try something like

```
if($.trim($("selector").html())=='')
```

or, as Adriano Repetti said in the comments:

```
if($("selector").children().length == 0)
```

which is more CPU-efficient

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just select by pseudo-selector in jquery than use `closest`.

```js
$(".status_comment_holder:empty")
  .closest(".well")
  .css("background-color", "red");
```

```css
.well {
  height: 1.2em;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well well-small comment-container">
  <div class="status_comment_holder"></div>
</div>

<div class="well well-small comment-container">
  <div class="status_comment_holder">Should be Green</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using plain vanilla javascript:

```js
function checkText() {

var imageComment = document.getElementById('image_comment');
var commentContainer = document.getElementById('comment-container');

if (imageComment.textContent.length === 0) {
    commentContainer.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
}

else {
    commentContainer.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(191,191,191)';
}

}

var imageComment = document.getElementById('image_comment');
imageComment.addEventListener('input',checkText,false);
```

```css
#comment-container {
width:400px;
height:100px;
padding:25px;
background-color: rgb(191,191,191);
}

#image_comment {
height:48px;
line-height:48px;
padding:12px;
font-size:48px;
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

```html
<div class="well well-small comment-container" id="comment-container">
<div class="status_comment_holder" id="image_comment" contenteditable="true">Delete this text...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use this:

```
if ( $('#image_comment').text().length == 0 ) {
    alert("fhfhf");
    $('.well').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#image_comment').is(':empty')){
       alert("fhfhf");
       $('.well').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
    }
});
```

You can see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/950xws7o/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Search for functions/DOM like `change(function())` , `keyup(function())` , `text()`

Hope you will get an answer for what your are looking.