# Javascript : Check <img> is empty generate by for loop and if true do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For instance we have something like below, which is generate brunch of `img` with different src  :

```
//the for loop is not important but just giving you some idea

    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
      <img class="emptyPic result-image" src="{{picURL}}"/>
     }
```

and I'd like to check every `img` onload, if it's src is empty like `<img src=""/>`, i would like to do something, but in the example just make it `display:none` first. So i tried something like below with JQuery.

```
if($(this + ".result-image").attr('src')){
  ($(this + ".result-image").css("display","none")
}
```

i had put the if statmenet above into the for loop already and it should do the job but what is it not working?

Comment: Why not just use CSS?  Something like: img[src = ''] {display:none;}

Comment: do you want to check if img src is empty???

Comment: You could hide the broken images, but Id say the right way would be to not create them in the first place which it sounds like you started to do *"i had put the if statmenet above into the for loop already and it should do the job but what is it not working?"* , What framework are you using? Angular or something judging by the `{{}}`?

Comment: Handlebar.js , i didn't make the decision, i would not create those img with broken link or empty src, but i am not the one in charge of the back-end system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure CSS:

```
img[src = ''] {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if img src is empty and want to do something...This may help;

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img src="" class="image">

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($('.image').attr('src') == '') { 
      alert('got me'); 
    }
});
```

If you want to check if it is empty....This may help

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img src="" class="image">

</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
if ($('.image').is(':empty')){
  alert("hi")
}
```

SOURCE:

[How do I check if an HTML element is empty using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery)

Hope this helps