# Loop Through Divs and Check If Child Div Has Content

Tags: jquery, if-statement, each, addclass

I'm looking to loop through divs, check if each has content within it's specific child div, if so add a class to the div.

```
  $('.img-banner').each(function( index, element ) {
    if ( $(element).find('.img-banner-content').length > 0 ) {
      $(element).addClass("has-content");
    }
  });
```

I'm missing something simple here and could do with a shake.  The issue is it's adding the class "has-content" to all divs.

Reduced test case: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yabe5s21/)

Thanks all.

Comment: Your only test here is to check if there's one or more `divs` within the parent `div`. There's nothing checking for their content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an HTML element is empty using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to actually check if there is text within the div.

`$(this).find('.img-banner-content').length` will always return true since it's not actually checking if that dom node has any `innerHTML`, just whether the dom-ref present.

So replace:

```
if ( $(this).find('.img-banner-content').length > 0 )
```

With:

```
if ( $(element).find('.img-banner-content').text().length > 0 )
```

Putting it together:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.img-banner').each(function( index, element ) {
    if ( $(element).find('.img-banner-content').text().length > 0 ) {
      $(element).addClass("has-content");
    }
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jg0w257q/

Comment: Alternatively and for more flexibility, use `.html()`. A `$.trim()` operation might also be used.

Comment: @4castle good point, but I'm not sure if the original intent is simply to check if there is text within the div, or if there is actually a bunch of dom nodes and stuff there

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink no, this is perfect. Just what I was looking for. Thank you for breaking in down. I was looking to check if there is text within the div.