# Hiding a div when the_field is empty

Tags: php, html, css

```
<div class="full-width awards">
    <h2><span>Awards</span></h2>
    <div id="accordion" class="accordion awards-list">

    <?php if (get_field( 'awards_&_festivals' ) ) : ?>

    <h3 class="award-title" ><span class="down-icon">Awards &amp; Festivals</span></h3>
    <div class="award-content" >
        <?php the_field( 'awards_&_festivals' ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

I wanted to hide the awards div when the_field does not have any content any idea on how to make this happen? Much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an HTML element is empty using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery)

Comment: To begin with you have 3 opening `div` tags and you only have 2 closing.

Comment: Which div you want to hide?

Comment: where is the_field ?

Comment: Since `the_field($field_name)` is equal to `echo get_field($field_name);` as noted in the docs, you can easily do as the docs demonstrates and use `if(get_field($field_name)) { //show html section here }` and not print anything at all for that section if empty. Then you don't have to rely on browser features that can be disabled by the user if desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We can do it like this -

```
if ($(".award-content").html() == "") {
    $('.awards').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With css you can hide it with `:empty` property

like

```
.someClass:empty {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can verify with PHP if has content and ignore div. With CSS you can use :empty selector
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp

```
.award-content:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Or change you PHP code:

```
<div class="full-width awards">
    <h2><span>Awards</span></h2>
    <div id="accordion" class="accordion awards-list">

    <?php if (!empty(get_field( 'awards_&_festivals' ) )) : ?>

    <h3 class="award-title" ><span class="down-icon">Awards &amp; Festivals</span></h3>
    <div class="award-content" >
        <?php the_field( 'awards_&_festivals' ); ?>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```