# What does an empty div mean in Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, is-empty

I have the following empty div inside my html page:

```
<div id='onlineaccess' style='width:20em;'>
</div>
```

I need to dynamically update this div with html, but before I do, I need to see if it is empty or not. I have written the following JQuery and Javascript code for this:

```
if($('#onlineaccess').is(':empty') ) 
{alert('No HTML inside of onlineaccess div');}
else
{alert('Some HTML inside of onlineaccess div');}
```

but this does not yield the result I am looking for if the div is empty.

```js
if($('#onlineaccess').is(':empty') ) 
{alert('No HTML inside of onlineaccess div');}
else
{alert('Some HTML inside of onlineaccess div');}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='onlineaccess' style='width:20em;'>
    </div>
```

This alerts the second message even if the div is empty. Can anyone explain to me why is it so and how can I get the first message into the alert?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: [`:empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/): "_Select all elements that have no children (**including text nodes**)_"

Comment: The `div` *isn't* empty.  It contains whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

```js
if($('#onlineaccess:empty') ) 
{alert('No HTML inside of onlineaccess div');}
else
{alert('Some HTML inside of onlineaccess div');}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='onlineaccess' style='width:20em;'>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the line break. Seems some browsers interpret this differently than others.

Write it this way:

```
<div id='onlineaccess' style='width:20em;'></div>
```

and you get your intended behaviour.

Related: [How do I check if an HTML element is empty using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery)

Comment: Instead of marking this question as a duplicate you post the duplicate as part of your answer? O.o

Comment: Don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var check = !$.trim( $('#div').html() ).length;

if (check) {
  console.log('no html');
} else {
  console.log('some html');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id='div' style='width:20em;'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the html() content of your id  so should be

```
  if($.trim($('#onlineaccess').html()) ==='' )
```

Answer (score 0):

The div is actually not empty, it has a text node inside which counts as non-empty contents. Use this insead:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($("#onlineaccess").html() === "") {
    console.log('empty');
  } else {
    console.log('not empty');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='onlineaccess' style='width:20em;'>
</div>
```