# JQuery detecting empty p tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to ask for some help with this one so here goes...

I'm creating a WYSIWYG editor using a contenteditable textarea. It automatically creates paragraphs and you can also add in subtitles.

What I would like to be able to do is when the button `#addStorySubtitle` is clicked, if the currently selected p tag is empty or only contains a zero width space `&#8203;`, then it will be replaced with the contents of innerDivSubtitle. However, if the p tag has content, use `innerDivSubtitle` to create a new block level element underneath.

The part I seem to be having trouble with is detecting is the p tag is empty.

Thanks all!

```
$('#addStorySubtitle').click(function(e){
  var innerDivSubtitle = $('<div class="addStorySubtitleWrap" contenteditable="false"><span class="removeStorySubtitle"></span><textarea name="addstorysubtitle" class="addStorySubtitle autoSize" placeholder="Really good subtitle" contenteditable="true"></textarea></div><p>&#8203;<p>');

  var sel = window.getSelection();
  if ($(sel.anchorNode.parentNode) === "") {
    alert('empty'); //just for help
    $(sel.anchorNode.parentNode).replaceWith(innerDivSubtitle);
  } else {
    alert('not empty'); //just for help
    $(sel.anchorNode.parentNode).after(innerDivSubtitle);
  }
});
```

UPDATE

Thanks for all of your helpful replies!

It turns out that the zero width space detection was causing the issue and I had to use unicode to detect it. Here's what I did to fix it...

```
    var nodCon = $(sel.anchorNode.parentNode).html();
    if (nodCon === "" || nodCon === "\u200b"){ 
     alert('empty');
    }
```

Comment: `alert` is not a debugger.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery

Comment: `p` tag shouldn't be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you?

```
if($('p').html() == "" || $('p').html == "&#8203;"){
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if empty the following way:

```
if ($("Your p tag").val().length == 0) { /* Empty */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the element has content like this:

```js
checkElementContents(document.getElementById('p1'));
checkElementContents(document.getElementById('p2'));

function checkElementContents(element) {
  if (element.innerHTML) {
    console.log(element.id + " is not empty");
  } else {
    console.log(element.id + " is empty");
  }
};
```

```html
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="p2"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with spaces, carriage return etc...

```
function isEmpty(ele)
{
   var count = ele.html().replace(/\s*/, '');
   if(count>0)
      return false;
   return true;
}

console.log(isEmpty($('p')));
```