# How to check whether a html column contains empty cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check whether a cells of a certain column of a html table is filled completely. The 5th column of the #mf-table could not be kept unfilled.

I used following function to select the column. It works fine.

```
$.fn.column = function(i) {
     return $('tr td:nth-child('+(i+1)+')', this);
 }
```

I used the following method to pop up a warning if column has empty cells.

```
if ($('#mf-table').column(5).is(":empty")) {      
        toastr.error('Fill empty fields');
    }
```

This method does not working. Can any one tell what is wrong here?

edit:

I tried following method. In order to test my code I colored the column 5 and it works fine. Here I have considered a situation where any of the cell is empty  in whole table

```
if ($('#mf-table tr td').is(":empty")) {
    $('#mf-table').column(5).css( "background-color", "red" )
}
```

So in the above method, if at least one cell is empty, the column 5 is colored. I need help to alter this method to check whether at least one cell is empty in column 5.

Comment: What is it doing instead?

Comment: It would be better, if you provide fiddler/plunker for this.

Comment: Are the table cells containing inputs? How do you let the user fill the table?

Comment: Users are able to upload files and details. Those inputs are appended to the table

Comment: I think this method looking for a completely empty column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```js
jQuery('table tr').each(function(){
 if(jQuery(this).children('td:empty').length > 0){
    console.log('Ther is Empty Cell');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function instead (copied [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery)):

```
function isEmpty( el ){
  return !$.trim(el.html())
}
```

Comment: How can I use this to check cells in a particular column

Comment: You should put jQuery element as a parameter. In your example it would be like: isEmpty($('#mf-table').column(5))