# show and hide a label depending on empty state

Tags: html, jquery, show-hide

I am appending several buttons into an html span tag every time I type on different inputs.

```
<span id="pill_filters>
  <button id="filterCreated">Filter name here</button>
  <button id="filterCreated2">Filter name here</button>
</span>
```

I also wanna show a label whenever there are buttons inside of this span tag and if they aren't, I wanna hide said label.

`<label id="label_sc">Search Criteria:</label>`

So far my jquery is

```
function showSCLabel(){
  if ($("#pill_filters").html.is(':empty')){
     $("#label_sc").addClass("d-none");
  }else{
   $("#label_sc").removeClass("d-none");
  }
}
```

But it doesnt seem to work. The label already has "d-none" class since the beginning and even with that, it is still showing. What am I doing wrong? is this not how the :empty state works? what can I use instead? I'll appreciate a lot your help!

Comment: How do you use `showSCLabel` ? Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an HTML element is empty using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `if` statement is missing `()`
- `.html.is` is invalid jQuery

Use:

```
if ( $("#pill_filters").is(':empty') ) {
```

Comment: Ah yes, I was missing the initial parenthesis, sorry. Let me correct, because, even with this, its still not working, sadly.

Comment: ah, I did run everything again, and it worked just fine. hehe. my bad!

Comment: @Falkirkh nice to hear you got this sorted

Answer (score 0):

Answer without jQuery:

```
//span
const span=document.getElementById("pill_filters");
//label
const label=document.getElementById("label-sc");

span.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
  //if innerHTML is not ""
  if(span.innerHTML){
    //show label
    label.style.display="block";
  }else{
    //hide label
    label.style.display="none";
  };
};
```