# How to check for empty div which has no text in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an html code as shown below in which `big-block` div is empty. What I want to achieve is if `big-block` div is empty
then apply css `display:none` on `hello-world` div.

```
<div class="hello-world">
   <h1 class="widget__title">Hello World</h1>
   <div class="big-block">
   
   </div>
</div>
```

This is what I have tried but unfortunately its not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if($('.hello-world .big-block').text().length == 0) {
        $('.hello-world').css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an HTML element is empty using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813227/how-do-i-check-if-an-html-element-is-empty-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what you can simplified version. just use `.text()` to see if there is something it `.big-block` div

As you mentioned that you have multiple `.big-block` divs so you can just check for a specific to be empty like this below. Just `.hello-world h1 div` to call that check specific only.

Fiddle **Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/bq5m8vyz/35/

Just run snippet to see in action.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if ($(".hello-world .big-block").children().length == 0 && $('.hello-world .big-block').text() == 0) {
    $('.hello-world').css("display", "none");
    console.log('.big-block is empty')
  } else {
    console.log('.big-block is NOT empty')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hello-world">
  <h1 class="widget__title">Hello World</h1>
  <div class="big-block">
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_self" class="featured-block__item cf">
      <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
        <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
          <img class="default-opacity" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/43/200/300.jpg?hmac=F_cVhLISpNmZ9wjirHfMJgX9rQzMYJbJE1xzfwmV36c" data-fallback-img="https://i.picsum.photos/id/43/200/300.jpg?hmac=F_cVhLISpNmZ9wjirHfMJgX9rQzMYJbJE1xzfwmV36c" alt="sdsd">
        </figure>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, can we do like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/nz9m6dy2/ The reason why I did in that way because there are multiple `big-block` class in my page. I want to call only the specific one.

Comment: @user1950349 I have updated my answer. Check the fiddle and answer now.

Comment: I tried your code in the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/sL27m4nx/ but its not working. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: @user1950349 I have updated my answer to exactly what you want. here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/bq5m8vyz/35/

Comment: Yes, it's working. Let me test few more times please.

Answer (score 1):

The big-block DIV contains whitespace, use `trim()` for removing that

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if(!$.trim($('.big-block').html())) {
        $('.hello-world').css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hello-world">
   <h1 class="widget__title">Hello World</h1>
   <div class="big-block">

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tz4c6ns0/3/) but its not working. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: Are you around ?

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can use regular expression to remove whitespace

```
<div id="item"></div>
console.log($('#item').text().length)  // 0


<div id="item"> </div>
console.log($('#item').text().length)  // 1 
console.log($('#item').text().replace(/\s/g, "").length)  // 0

<div id="item">
</div>
console.log($('#item').text().length)  // 5
console.log($('#item').text().replace(/\s/g, "").length)  // 0
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked and trying to archive as per the question. Thanks anyway :)